# $\sum c_{n}u_{n}$ converges if $\sum c_{n}$ converges absolutely and $\sum u_{n}$ converges.

Tags: calculus

$\sum c_{n}u_{n}$ converges if $\sum c_{n}$ converges absolutely and $\sum u_{n}$ converges. How should I solve it? do I have to consider that $u_{n}$ is bounded?

Answer (score 5):

If $\sum u_n$ converges then $u_n \to 0$ (the converse needn't be true). In particular, the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is bounded, so there is some $M > 0$ such that $\max\{|u_n|:n \in \Bbb{N}\} \leq M$. Now, $\sum |u_n c_n| \leq M \sum |c_n|$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: But how can we prove that $u_{n}$ is bounded if $\sum u_{n}$ is convergent?

Comment: *Every* convergent sequence is bounded. The idea is that if it converges, the terms are eventually "close" to the limit (contained within an arbitrarily small ball around the limit, which means bounded). And @Tom just mentioned that if $\sum u_n$ converges then so does $u_n$.

Comment: so, because M an finite number and since $\sum c_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, $M\sum \left | c_{n} \right |$ is convergent. So, by using the Comparison test, $sum \left | c_{n}u_{n} \right |$ is convergent. Am I getting it right?

Comment: If you have a sequence of *non-negative* numbers $\{a_n\}$ The partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ are non-decreasing as $N$ increases (since you're only adding on more non-negative terms as $N$ gets larger). Since every non-decreasing sequence of real numbers converges if and only if it is bounded above, you can deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if there is some bound $R > 0$ such that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \leq R$. Now, letting $S = \sum|c_n|$, then  you have that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |u_n c_n| \leq M\cdot S$.